# Should I use glue or silicone when installing door sweep seal?

Tags: doors, weatherstripping

I've been working on repairing my outside door which rotted away on the side. The weather strip on the bottom has two cuts that it slides into, but it looks like the original installation had some kind of glue or silicone also.  Along with three really long u-shaped nails. So when I go to install the new one, should I put some caulk down or some glue and then nail it?  I scraped the old whatever it was off with a putty knife.

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A sweep like this is intended to be self-sealing. Not much water will get past the first mounting rib, and if it does you'd want it to be able to dry out to prevent rot. The caulk that was there was mostly intended to help secure the sweep, so adding a bead between ribs isn't a bad idea.

I would also use a few small corrosion-resistant nails, particularly near the ends. There can be a lot of tug on a door sweep, and while the ribs are designed to hold the sweep in place, older wood may not grab as well as it did when new.